# GWT cannot find *native method* from "User Module" at compile time

Tags: java, gwt, timer, native

I am trying to integrate my GWT code with Guice/GIN (as it needs different config on the client, in the JVM (shared code), and when running tests). I am now getting a strange error about not finding a method when compiling:

```
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
...
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.createCallback(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Timer;I)Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.createCallback(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.scheduleRepeating(Timer.java:121)
[INFO]  at ...
```

com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer resides in the User module, and Timer.scheduleRepeating() is written in Java, and delegates to Timer.createCallback(), which is a "native" (JavaScript) method. So the compiler finds Timer itself, and Timer.scheduleRepeating(), but not the native method.

What could cause this? I did not have this issue before trying to use GIN.

EDIT: Since others seem to see different code, here is what *I* see when looking at com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer:

```
...
  private static native JavaScriptObject createCallback(Timer timer, int cancelCounter) /*-{
    return $entry(function() { timer.@com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer::fire(I)(cancelCounter); });
  }-*/;
...
  public void scheduleRepeating(int periodMillis) {
    if (periodMillis <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("must be positive");
    }
    if (isRunning()) {
      cancel();
    }
    isRepeating = true;
    timerId = Impl.setInterval(createCallback(this, cancelCounter), periodMillis);
  }
...
```

Comment: Look at [GWT Timer Class](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) that doesn't have any `createCallback()` method. Please share the code of your native method.

Comment: Look at [Diff - gwt Git repositories](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/5f1288de4e34e0bc8ae6b277ff60d2109363b7a5%5E!/)

Comment: I think it's an `INFO` not an `ERROR` as shown in your logs.

Comment: May be its a GWT version issue. Please try with latest GWT version.

Comment: @Braj OK, I see what you mean. Maybe the version I see in *Eclipse* is different then the one *Maven* sees?

Comment: Let try it again as I suggested in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You have added a new dependencies in the project.

Please clean the project and re-compile it again.

- Remove `gwt-unitCache` and other auto generated stubs also as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm using GWT 2.6.0, GIN 2.1.2 and Guice (and -assistedinject) 3.0. I think those are the correct version. Doing as you suggested did not fix the error. But I found the issue, so I'll post the answer myself.

Comment: It's a good news. Please post it as answer to make it helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I worked it out. In the GIN module, I am injecting some piece of code that needed to create a GWT Timer. And the problem was, that GIN *execute the module at compile time*. Of course, at compile time, the GWT Timer "native code" was not available, since that happened in the JVM itself.

So I just tried to catch the UnsatisfiedLinkError and ignore it. But that die not work out directly either, because UnsatisfiedLinkError is not available in GWT, so I just caught "Error" instead, and checked the class name. Then it all worked. But not before I discovered, to my dismay, that *I cannot override a "provideXXX()" method* on a GIN module (why?). Also, *even if it is allowed for a GIN module to be abstract, GIN still requires a public no-arg constructor* (which GIN will *never call*, because an abstract class cannot be instantiated!).